# Dynamic forms, Table meta data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, metadata

I am working with an ASP.Net web app that allows users to create an "application."

They define fields and their data types.  Based on that, I generate a query to create a table.

I would like to use the metadata from the table to generate an input form to display to users.

- Is this a good approach?
- Has anybody done a similar project
  that can share some lessons learned?
- How about creating and altering
  tables at runtime?
- Does anybody see any problems with
  that?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to accomadate for all userdefined field types (text, number lookup, dropdowns, check boxes, dates, etc).

These will have to be save to the ***database per field type per user per forms*.**

Further you will have to allow the user to define their own layout. this will mean that you have to same the entire form layout, ***per user per form per control***.

There are some apps available, that applies this logic, (I think [SharePoint](http://www.sharepointhq.com/resources/what_is_SP.htm) has this type of approach).

I have done this once before, but it was using WinForms, using [XtraLayoutControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Layout/) , DevExpress Layout Controls.

This did allow me to save the layout, but did not create the controls for me automatically. I still had to implement that my self.

If you have any specific questions, regarding db table layout, client integration, or performance of these queries, *Please feel free to ask*.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I'm not so concerned about the layout.  Of greatest interest to me is whether this is a good approach.  Is using DB metadata for my application's metadata a good idea?  Is modifying the table structure at runtime a good idea?  What are alternatives?